# Update query to remove seconds from "General Date" field in Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, sql-update

I am trying to write an Access SQL update query to re-format the "DateTime" column I have in my table. Currently, the column has the "General Date" format of "mm/dd/yy hh:nn:ss AM/PM", but I would like to remove seconds completely. What would be the syntax to re-format a column in an update query?

I was thinking it might be something along the lines of

```
UPDATE allPower.DateTime To Format([DateTime], "mm/dd/yy hh:nn AM/PM");
```

But there is a syntax error. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `UPDATE allPower set [DateTime ] = Format([DateTime], "mm/dd/yy hh:nn AM/PM");`

Comment: I found that another problem my query had was using "DateTime" as a field name, as that is already a reserved word in Access.

Comment: This is why you need the square brackets around the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct syntax :

```
UPDATE allPower
SET DateTime = Format([DateTime], "mm/dd/yy hh:nn AM/PM")
```

But you should not do this in a database, a database is made only for data storage. If you want to format your data, you could do this in the client side.

Answer (score 2):

You are somewhat derailed. A date *value* carries no format. The format is for *display* only.

Thus, if you wish to *display* no seconds, use the format: *mm/dd/yy hh:nn AM/PM*

If you wish to *update the stored values* to have no seconds, never use string handling, but adjust the values, for example:

```
UPDATE 
    allPower
SET 
    [DateTime] = DateValue([DateTime]) + TimeSerial(Hour([DateTime]), Minute([DateTime]), 0)
```